# object get with mixin or def in models

Tags: python, django

is it possible to issue a `get` result, only with certain fields in `models`, and not all? where fields must be defined inside `models`, like `def` or `mixin`. something like `clean_data` if a method is requested

**view**

```
cls = Class.objects.get(related_uuid='xxx')
```

you only need to display `device` and `related_uuid`, but define this in `models.py` itself, not in `views.py`

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)    
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to do.

Comment: I need the get result to be flushed in the model itself

Comment: so that 'object.get' will return by key a record with already filtered fields

Comment: that is, you just need to return the record, but without some of the fields